# Visual Studio C++ single-stepping through code in release build

Tags: visual-c++

I'm aware that single-stepping through code in release build can cause the arrow indicating the current code execution point to skip around to some (at least superficially) weird and misleading places. My question is: is there anything predictable and intelligible going on that one can read about, and which might help solve issues that occur in release build only, but not in debug build?

Concrete example I'm trying to get to the bottom of: (works in debug, not in release)

```
void Function1( void )
{
  if ( someGlobalCondition )
    Function2( 10 );
  else
    Function2();
}

void Function2( const int parameter = 1 )    // see note below
{
  DoTheActualWork();    // any code at all
}

// and finally lets call Function1() from somewhere...
Function1();
```

Note: for brevity I've skipped the fact that both functions are declared in header files, and implemented separately in .cpp files. So the default parameter notation in `Function2()` has had some liberties taken with it.

OK - so in Debug, this works just fine. In Release, even though there is a clear dependence on `someGlobalCondition`, the code pointer always skips completely over the body of `Function1()` and executes `Function2()` directly, but always uses the default parameter (and never `10`). This kinda suggests that `Function1()` is being optimised away at compile time... but is there any basis for drawing such conclusions? Is there any way to know for certain if the release build has actually checked `someGlobalCondition`?

P.S. (1) No this is not an XY question. I'm giving the context of Y so I can make question X make more sense. (2) No I will not post my actual code, because that would emphasise the Y question, which has extraordinarily low value to anyone but me, whereas the X question is something that has bugged me (and possibly others) for years.

Comment: try to set variables in `someGlobalCondition` as volatile

Comment: Nice suggestion for the Y question, which I've upvoted, even though it didn't actually work in my case. But... I really can't emphasise enough that I want to know where to find useful documentation that might shine light on the X question.

Comment: Does function `Function2` execution depends on `parameter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than seek documentation to explain the apparently inexplicable, switch to the Disassembly view when you single step. You will get to see exactly how the compiler has optimised your code and how it has taken account of everything... because it *will* have taken account of everything.

If you see no evidence of run-time tests for conditions (e.g. `jne` or `test` or `cmp` etc) then you can safely assume that the compiler has determined your condition(s) to be constant, and you can investigate why that is. If you see evidence of conditions being tested, but never being satisfied, then that will point you in another direction.

Also, if you feel the benefits of optimisation don't outweigh the costs of unintelligible code execution point behaviour, then you can always turn optimisation off.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the absence of your *actual* code, all we can surmise is that the compiler is figuring out that `someGlobalCondition` is never true.

That's the only circumstance in which it could correctly optimise out `Function1` and always call `Function2` directly with a `1` parameter.

If you want to be *certain* that this optimisation is happening, your best bet is to analyse either the assembler code or machine code generated by the compiler.

Comment: Sorry - I'm going to downvote because you're answering the Y question that I've explicitly said is only there to contextualise and give an example of the X question. How do you "know" this to be true? If there is documentation somewhere that would prove it? That might provide a useful answer to the X question that I would upvote instead.